# C++ ftell Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles, fread

I am trying to read data from a binary file. I have been given a struct with all of the variables to extract the data. I am using the fread function, and I need to get the total size of the file as one of freads inputs. I am using the ftell function to find the size, but I get a segmentation fault when I call the ftell function.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct header{
  int so_on; 
  int so_forth;
  int etc;
};

int main(){
  FILE *fin;
  header cvvHeader;
  fin=fopen("file.binaryextension","r");
  int headersize= sizeof(header);
  header* ptr=&cvvHeader;
  long filesize =ftell (fin); //Segmentation fault happens here
  fread(ptr,headersize,filesize,fin);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can´t see something wrong with ftell, but some other errors: Open with "rb" instead of "r"; parameter 2+3 of fread make no sense, fclose is missing, endianess and struct order/packing are not considered. @ftell-thing: Is this exactly the (a) code which crashes or some minimized example?

Comment: check if (fin != null) first?

Comment: besides the problems already mentioned: what do you expect to return ftell() on a freshly opened file?

Answer (score 3):

Your following code is creating problem, You need to check whether fin is valid or NULL.

```
fin=fopen("file.binaryextension","r");
//....code
long filesize =ftell (fin); //Segmentation fault happens here



// fin should be non-null pointer when file is successfully opened. 
if(fin) {
  long filesize =ftell (fin); 
  }
```

Comment: Found my problem. fin was null because I had the file misspelled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Several problems:**

1. In order to open file `file.binaryextension` for reading, you need to have it in the correct path:

   If you are running your program directly (e.g., by clicking it, or by calling it from a command-line), then it should be in the same path as the executable file.

   If you are running your program from Visual Studio, then the path is usually where the `vcproj` file is located. Alternatively, you can change the path itself within the project settings.
2. In order to obtain the size of the file:

   Call `fseek(fin,0,SEEK_END)`.

   Call `long filesize = ftell(fin)`.

   Call `fseek(fin,0,SEEK_SET)`.
3. In order to read the header data from the file:

   Call `fread(ptr,headersize,1,fin)`.
4. In order to read the remaining data from the file:

   Call `char* data = (char*)malloc(filesize-headersize)`.

   Call `fread(data,filesize-headersize,1,fin)`.

   Call `free(data)` when you finish using it.